# How many elements of order 6 are in $S_5$?

Tags: group-theory

How many elements of order 6 are in $S_5$?

Here is my solution:
possible cycle structures are $[2,3]$. Applying class equation gets $5! \over 2!3! $ = $10$. Is my solution correct?

Comment: How did you get that out of the class equation? IOW: No.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your solution is incorrect: you are undercounting.

You are correct that an element of order $6$ in $S_5$ must be the product of a $2$-cycle and a disjoint $3$-cycle. 
$$\binom{5}{2} = \frac{5!}{2!3!}$$
counts the number of ways of selecting $2$ elements from $5$; in essence, you are counting the number of $2$-cycles; of course, the $3$-cycle will then consist of the three remaining elements... but there are *two* possibilities, not one.

For example, if we select $1$ and $2$ for the $2$-cycle, you get the elements $(1\;2)(3\;4\;5)$ *and* $(1\;2)(3\;5\;4)$. These are distinct elements.

The order of the two elements chosen for the $2$-cycle does not matter, since $(a\;b)=(b\;a)$; but the order of the elements of the $3$-cycle *does* matter: $$(a\;b\;c) = (b\;c\;a) = (c\;a\;b)\neq (a\;c\;b)=(b\;a\;c) = (c\;b\;a).$$

Comment: oops, I $5! \over 6$ I think.

Comment: In other words, two for every $2$-cycle. Yes.